# How to set the same scale range for all the choropleth maps?

Tags: python, maps, data-visualization, choropleth

So, I decided to challenge myself to do choropleth maps of new corona cases per Brazilian states, from 2020 to 2022. The issue I'm having is that these maps don't all have the same scale, or the same range on the scale, so it can lead to misleading interpretation.  The legend or color bar that appears on the right side is the legend of the first map, and it is not the same for all the maps. How can I make all the maps have the same scale, ranging from 0 to 4.5?

*Here is my code:*

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

states_info = gpd.read_file(r'C:\Users\lepae\Documents\IGTI\Programação\Udemy - Python for Data Science and Machine Learning Bootcamp\Py_DS_ML_Bootcamp-master\Refactored_Py_DS_ML_Bootcamp-master\09-Geographical-Plotting\bcim_2016_21_11_2018.gpkg', layer = 'lim_unidade_federacao_a')

corona_cases = pd.read_csv('HIST_PAINEL_COVIDBR_2022_Parte1_14abr2022.csv',  sep=';')

merged_df = pd.merge(left=states_info, right=corona_sum, left_on='sigla', right_on='estado')
#(repeats same process for all the semesters)
#...

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,3, figsize=(16,10), 
                        constrained_layout=True, 
                        sharex=True, sharey=True, 
                        subplot_kw=dict(aspect='equal'))

merged_df_2020_01.plot(column='casosNovos', ax=axs[0,0], figsize = (16,10), cmap = 'Reds', edgecolor= 'black')
axs[0,0].set_title('First semester of 2020')

merged_df_2020_02.plot(column='casosNovos', ax=axs[0,1], figsize = (16,10), cmap = 'Reds', edgecolor= 'black')
axs[0,1].set_title('Second semester of 2020')

merged_df_2021_01.plot(column='casosNovos', ax=axs[0,2], figsize = (16,10), cmap = 'Reds', edgecolor= 'black')
axs[0,2].set_title('First semester of 2021')

merged_df_2021_02.plot(column='casosNovos', ax=axs[1,0], figsize = (16,10), cmap = 'Reds', edgecolor= 'black')
axs[1,0].set_title('Second semester of 2021')

merged_df.plot(column='casosNovos', ax=axs[1,1], figsize = (16,10), cmap = 'Reds', edgecolor= 'black')
axs[1,1].set_title('First semester of 2022')

fig.delaxes(axs[1,2])
fig.suptitle('Number of new cases of COVID-19 per Brazilian States', fontsize=20, y=1.05)
patch_col = axs[0,0].collections[0]
cb = fig.colorbar(patch_col, ax=axs, shrink = 0.95)
```

**Image of what I have so far:**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9bKy.png

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same problem, and I found this link, which helped me fix it.
Basically, it says to enter a vmax value, so that the range is forced to be increased to a specific value.
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/439233/use-geopandas-to-force-a-choropleth-to-use-a-legend-with-a-greater-range-than-th/439363

In your case, since you want the range to be set up until 4.5, you'd set your vmax to 4.5

```
cb = fig.colorbar(patch_col, ax=axs, shrink = 0.95, vmax = 4.5)
```